# Load native library failed for file tensorflow_jni.dll

Tags: java, tensorflow

I'm trying to load Java native library for running TensorFlow in Java using jni, but if I try to load `tensorflow_jni.dll` ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_java)) with syntax `System.loadLibrary()` it causes the error shown below

My code to load the file:

```
public class tensor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadfile("tensorflow_jni");
    }

    public static boolean loadfile(String path) {
        System.loadLibrary(path);

        return true;
    }
}
```

The error I receive:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin\tensorflow_jni.dll: PèÊþ
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(ClassLoader.java:2440)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2497)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:2694)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2648)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:806)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1906)
    at tensor/tensor.tensor.loadfile(tensor.java:10)
    at tensor/tensor.tensor.main(tensor.java:6)
```

But if I try to load other JNI files like this

```
public class tensor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        loadfile("saproc");
    }

    public static boolean loadfile(String path) {
        System.loadLibrary(path);

        return true;
    }
}
```

It runs without error

Comment: What is the full path to file _tensorflow_jni_ and what is the full path to file _saproc_ ?

Comment: both are in same directory for testing pusposes i place tensorflow_jni.dll in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13\bin;